# how to use other_urls = [] inside __init__() to store multiple urls and then call parse()

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

My spider code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from selenium import webdriver
from youtube.items import YoutubeItem
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from datetime import date
import re
import math
from scrapy.http import Request


class YoutubeSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "youtube"
    allowed_domains = ['youtube.com']

    device_name = "nexus 6 "
    start_urls = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+device_name+"\"unboxing\""
    other_urls = []

def __init__(self):
    other_ulrs = []
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def parse(self, response):
    items = []
    self.driver.get(self.start_urls)

    d1 =self.driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
    html = str(d1)
    response = TextResponse('none',200,{},html,[],None)

    '''
    my parse code......
    '''

    self.driver.close()
    return items
```

But my code only working for the `start_urls` correctly, I've a file that contain device name `device_name.txt` , I want to send these name and call parse method.

I'm using this inside `__init__()`:

```
other_urls = [l.strip() for l in open('device_name.txt').readlines()]
```

and before return inside `parse():` I'm using this `if` to call `other_urls` but its not working.

```
if self.other_urls:
    return Request(self.other_urls.pop(0), meta={'items': [items]})

self.driver.close()
return items
```

Comment: I think you should be using `self.other_urls = [l.strip() for l in ...]` since otherwise it will be assigned to a function-local variable. Emphasis on the `self` part.

Comment: And you should use `yield` instead of `return` because if you mix up `items` with `Request`s then you need a generator function.